# how to execute server side click event after jquery pop up messgae

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[id*=btnModalPopup]").live("click", function () {
        $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
            title: "jQuery Modal Dialog Popup",
            buttons: {
                ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    __doPostBack('btnModalPopup', 'OnClick');
                    //document.getElementById("btnModalPopup").click();
                }
            },
            modal: true
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="modal_dialog" style="display: none">
        This is a Modal Background popup
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnModalPopup" runat="server" Text="Show Modal Popup" ClientIDMode="static"  OnClick="btnModalPopup_Click" />

</form>
</body>
```

Above Code Shows J query popup Message.It Works fine. but after popup message i need to execute server Side Code 
if i Remove Return False from the script it execute the server Side Code But Popup message disappears. It should execute After popup's OK button Click

Please help....

Comment: When's the server side supposed to be called? After user closes the popup?

Comment: Use OnClientClick property to call your javascript and server side code to OnClick property. Hope This helps

Comment: @artm Yes it should execute after User click Ok Button of the Popup

Answer (score 0):

**Server Side Method**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
        + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

**Client Side**

```
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CS.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
        data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
             //do
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
    btnModalPopup_Click();
}
```

[Call ASP.Net Page Method using jQuery AJAX Example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add `ClientIdMode='static'` to your button, return false from your event handler and try this in your OK button callback

```
 OK: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
      __doPostBack('btnModalPopup','OnClick');
 }
```

Comment: Hi @KeDaR. I have used that method many times successfully. Can you attach the code that didn't work? You may need to manually process the postback on your page load to call the right method i.e btnModalPopup

Comment: how i can attach the Code ?

Comment: @KeDaR Looks like you've attached the client code to your question. When you say it didn't work, is it the client side or the server side? Does the page_load get called on the server side when you use __doPostBack?

Comment: when i click on ok Button No Page Load get called

Comment: @KeDaR Have you added `ClientIdMode='static'` to your button?

Comment: YES <asp:Button ID="btnclient" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" Text="Show Modal Popup" />

Comment: @KeDaR It's the `btnModalPopup` that needs the clientIdMode=static, you're calling __doPostBack for that button.

Comment: No,you can check my updated code $("[id*=btnclient]").live("click", function () and btnClient have ClientIDMode='static'

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnModalPopup" runat="server" Text="Show Modal Popup" OnClick="btnModalPopup_Click" Style="display: none" /> thisis the button with the server side callback, isn't it?

Comment: sorry thr is litle bit of confusion,i've Updated my Code.Page Load not get Called